# Detecting behaviour change in a recommender system

Tags: machine-learning, entropy, recommender-system, monitoring

Suppose I want to track a recommender system's live performance. The task isn't exactly to detect outliers, but to detect if the system started behaving differently, looking at the output only - an example event I'd like to detect is if it starts outputting higher-entropy probabilities than it did straight after launch.

I'm struggling to find specific prior work/advice on this. Tracking quantiles of entropies feels unsubstantiated. Any pointers appreciated!